Seeking characteristics of the final-digits distribution of primes
Recently, I've been interested in the distributional characteristics of the numbers {1, 3, 7, 9} in the final-digits of prime numbers, and I'm wondering if there are any current articles devoted to studying the distributional patterns of the final-digits of prime numbers, such as theorems, conjectures, or the like. I searched the internet and there are very few specialized articles. I don't know, is there any enthusiastic mathematician who can share some link text with me, thanks!

Primes in arithmetic progressions $\pmod n$ are equidistributed amongst the possible classes, by Dirichlet.

FYI, there's Wikipedia's Prime number race section, which says "Dirichlet's theorem states that asymptotically, $25$% of all primes end in each of these four digits. However, empirical evidence shows that the number of primes that end in $3$ or $7$ less than $n$ tends to be slightly bigger than the number of primes that end in $1$ or $9$ less than $n$ (a generation of the Chebyshev's bias). This follows that $1$ and $9$ are quadratic residues modulo $10$, and $3$ and $7$ are quadratic nonresidues modulo $10$".

Cf. Prime Number Races
by Andrew Granville and Greg Martin
The American Mathematical Monthly , Jan., 2006, Vol. 113, No. 1
pp. 1-33

@JohnOmielan  Thank you very much for the recommendation!

@J.W.Tanner Thank you very much for the recommendation!
